# Unable to validate field values in custom button

Tags: javascript, community, custom-button

Hi friends i got a requirement in cases.I have record type called VARMA. and we have a standard button called **"Save & Edit"** so, whenever support rep click this button we need to validate subject could not be null.

So, i am created a custom button and i am unable to hide the standard button from record edit page.

And My custom code will be.

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
var reason = "{!Case.Subject}";
if(Subject == null || Subject == ''){
alert("Please Enter Subject")
}
else {
window.open('/{!Case.Id}/s?retURL=%2{!Case.Id}');
}
```

But it will displaying error like

> Subject is not defined

How to hide or replace standard Save & Close button with new custom button in record edit page.

Comment: That last addition is a ***completely separate question***. You should ask it separately...

Comment: Ok thanks.I am going close this question.@Adrian Larson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use your reason variable.

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
var reason = "{!Case.Subject}";
if(reason == null || reason == ''){
alert("Please Enter Subject")
}
else {
window.open('/{!Case.Id}/s?retURL=%2{!Case.Id}');
}
```

Comment: But is there any way to hide standard Save & close button in record edit page.

Comment: But i am bale to display only in detail page.Is there any way to replace standard one with custom.@Martin Lezer